# SKCropNode making masked image disappear entirely

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an image I want to partially mask (wallSprite), an image to act as a mask over it (wallMaskBox), and a node to hold both (wallCropNode). When I simply add both images as children of wallCropNode, both image display correctly:

```
var wallSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wall.png")

var wallCropNode = SKCropNode()

var wallMaskBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blacksquaretiny.png")
wallMaskBox.zPosition = 100

wallCropNode.addChild(wallSprite)
wallCropNode.addChild(wallMaskBox)
gameplayContainerNode.addChild(wallCropNode)
```

But when I set the mask image as a `maskNode` property of the crop node:

```
var wallSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wall.png")

var wallCropNode = SKCropNode()

var wallMaskBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blacksquaretiny.png")
wallMaskBox.zPosition = 100

wallCropNode.addChild(wallSprite)
wallCropNode.maskNode = wallMaskBox
gameplayContainerNode.addChild(wallCropNode)
```

the wallSprite image disappears entirely, instead of being partly cropped. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you got the alpha/non-alpha parts inversed? Try making the black square transparent where it is now opaque and vice versa.

Comment: Still not working. I tried a half-opaque, half-transparent mask image to see if there was a difference, but I see nothing on either side. Any other thoughts?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I think posting the images would be helpful.

Comment: @0x141E Sure, thank you. Here's the [black square](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15500233/stackoverflow/blacksquaretiny.png), and some [screenshots](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15500233/stackoverflow/mask.png) of what I see in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your black square image is completely opaque. Some (or all) of its pixels should be transparent (i.e., alpha = 0). The pixels that correspond to the mask node's transparent pixels will be masked out (i.e., not rendered) in the cropped node. To demonstrate this, I used your code to create the following.

Here's the original image:

[image]

Here's the mask image that I used for the `maskNode`. Note that the white regions are transparent (i.e., alpha = 0). From Apple's documentation,

> When rendering its children, each pixel is verified against the
>   corresponding pixel in the mask. If the pixel in the mask has an alpha
>   value of less than 0.05, the image pixel is masked out. Any pixel not
>   rendered by the mask node is automatically masked out.

[image]

and here's the cropped node. I took a screenshot of the scene from the iPhone 6 simulator.

[image]